# Chromecast PDF application for Chrome/iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, casting, chromecast

Does anyone know how difficult it would be to make a Chromecast app that casts PDFs from an iOS device or Chrome browser to a Chromecast? I have tried to cast a tab with a PDF and it does not work well. I wondered why noone has made a PDF.js like application for casting PDFs. I am not a good programmer, but it just seems to me that it ought to be something a lot of people would like to have. Most of my presentations can easily be converted to PDFs.

Comment: You asked the same question a few days ago (Oct 25), so please stop asking the very same question repeatedly.

Comment: PDF.js works for me okay on Androi and using Chrome extension at resolutions allowed by the device.